# Android studio is not applying country-specific language settings

Tags: android, locale

I want to implement the language change function only inside the app. Supported languages ​​are "en", "fr", "ko", "ru" and "zh". The code is below.

```
private fun setLocale(lang: String) {
    val locale = Locale(lang)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val config = resources.configuration
    baseContext.createConfigurationContext(config)
    config.setLocale(locale)
    resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)
}
```

In xml code, @string xml was created to create languages ​​for each country.

[image]

The text entered in the Textview was put as @string/value. At first, it turned out well as the language was set, but over time the language is only available in English. `updateConfiguration` is deprecated. Is it related to this?? How do I set it up to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

In the MainActivity us the following code to make sure the locale setting is kept after app restart.

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    newBase?.let { base ->
        //get the locale that should be displayed
        val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(base)
        val languageCode = sharedPref.getString(base.resources.getString(R.string.keyLocale), defaultLocale)
        
        languageCode?.let { languageCode ->
            //check the current selected locale
            val config = base.resources.configuration
            val current = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24){
                config.locales[0]
            } else {
                config.locale
            }

            //if current locale is not the selected locale, then change the langauge                
            if(current.language != languageCode){
                val locale = Locale(languageCode)
                config.setLocale(locale)
                base.createConfigurationContext(config)
            }
        }
    }

    super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
}
```

If you want to change the langauge after a user input. Simply add this after you saved the user choice.

```
context?.let {context ->
    if(context is MainActivity){
        context.recreate()
    }
}
```